# Is there a way to convert Jhipster project to react project separately?

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I have a project managed by jhipster developed in frontend in react and in backend in spring and I want to extract the front part separately from the jhipster project.
Is it possible?

Comment: Have you read this doc? https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/

Comment: I don't want to use jhipster anymore
I want to create a purely react projectwithout going through jhipster

Comment: What about creating an empty React app using create-react-app and then move all your existing frontend code to it?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do but the front part is very complex and I can't make the correspondence.
that's why I'm asking you if there is an easier alternative to migration

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way, it's a manual task but fortunately it should be "only" about build process, the code itself should not change. At least, that's my experience for having gone through this for Angular.

Comment: So I'll try to rewrite the code manually